# Capturing and storing a picture with UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to capture and save a picture using the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() funciton.  Here is the code I have right now.

```
    @IBAction func CameraAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

So essentially I created an object called picker with the UIImagePickerController() class.  I want to use the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() function so that I can save the photo that was just taken with the code above to the photo album.  I know there are 4 parameters in total that I need to use in order to correctly use the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() function.  I figured for the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th parameter I can set it to nil. I'm mainly confused about the first parameter.  I know its supposed to be a UIImage.  How to I get the picture I just took with the code above as a UIImage?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add UIImagePickerControllerDelegate delegate tinyour viewcontroller class
2. Implement the completion method

   ```
   func imagePickerController(picker:UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:NSDictionary)
   {
           if(picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)
   {
               // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
               var imageToSave: UIImage = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as UIImage

      UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil)
               self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Should I add the closing parenthesis to the if statement?

Comment: Yeah, i missed the closing parenthesis

Comment: I was having a couple of problems with your solution.  Is your solution written in Objective C?

Comment: Nope its in swift. Whats the problem?